# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: discord.js

```js
exports.delGuild = function(guild){
  db.run("DELETE FROM guilds WHERE id = ?", guild.id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err.message);
    console.log(`guild ${guild.id} removed from database`);
  });
}
```

I don't know why that happens just sometimes, but the program crashes.

Comment: `guild` is null - **baboom!** - so, find out why/when the code is *calling* `delGuild` with an invalid (*cough* null *cough*) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're properly defining the guild, when you call the delGuild function, make sure you're calling it like so; `file.delGuild(guild)`